# Finding string length without using library function

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-length

I'm coding a function to find the string length without using the standard headers. I completed the code with start to end but when I'm returning the count at the end, it is not returning (Point 1) the correct answer.

Eg:

```
Enter name:
ISRO
Name is ISRO
Length is 4
&
Process returned 17
```

Code:

```
int stringlength (char[]);

void main()
{
    char str[20];
    int len;
    printf("Enter name:\n");
    gets(str);
    printf("Your name is %s\n",str);
    len = stringlength(str);
    printf("Name length is %d\n", len);

}

int stringlength (char x[])
{
    int i=0,count=0;

    while(x[i] != '\0')
    {
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    return count; (Point 1)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*(Point 1)*"? In addition, please also clarify your output (the one you have given is the expected one?).

Comment: `i` and `count` have the same value in `stringlength` function. You can drop one of them. Also, the output looks correct

Comment: Most probably it's not `void main()`, but `int main()`

Comment: Do you use some IDE? Or what compiler do you use? Try making it `int main()` and in the end of main functions `return 0;`

Comment: What length do you expect to get for `"ISRO"` if not `4` ?

Comment: Hi, Your sample output doesn't actually match your code. For example the output says "Name is" but the code prints "Your name is". I'm not trying to be petty. It's just really important that you include the exact version of code your having difficulty with.

Comment: Apart from beeing too complicated, the code of your `stringlength` function looks correct to me. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are confused because of the line "Process returned 17". Typically line like that printed by IDE. It's because `main` has to return an exit code. Declare `main` function as `int main()` and add `return 0;` in the end.

In real it returns the result of the last function. In your case, it's `printf` which return the number of printed characters.

Comment: @P.Dmitry you should mention that is printed by whatever framework/IDE etc. the OP and that it is not part of the output of the program.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - Indeed, Visual Studio doesn't have a problem - process exits with 0. However, for declarations like `void main()` return value is UB - see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function (towards the end of the page).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function `gets()` has been removed from the `C` standard, and should not be used (however, many compilers and platforms still implement it). Thus, I'm not sure how your implementation handles it. In Visual Studio 2019, I run your program and it works! (MSVC has `gets` in the runtime library but not in the headers, so it sees it as "unknown returning int," which would allow it to use the code in the binary RTL.)

However, if I change `gets(str);` for the standard `fgets(str, 20, stdin);` then I get a length of one longer than I (or you) would expect. (Is this what you're seeing?)

The reason for the 'extra' character is that the `fgets` function returns a string that ***includes*** the terminating newline character.

Comment: Hi, just to be exact `gets()` has been definitively removed (not just deprecated) as of C11. It is deprecated in C++. I believe it's the first and only function ever removed.
I can't find the quote but the view of the standards committee was that it was such a vulnerability that any code using it should be regarded as already broken!

Comment: @Adrian I do not know who down-voted your answer. As for me then I upvoted it.:)

Comment: @Persixty - You are correct! I have edited my answer accordingly - hope you approve.

Comment: @Adrian I do. I just think it's worth emphasising just how bad `gets()` is seen. Worst. Library. Function. Ever!

Comment: @Adrian the issue here is probably the incorrect signature of `main` which should be `int main()`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `gets` is not a standard C function that is it is not supported any more by the C Standard. Use instead the standard function `fgets`.

For example

```
printf( "Enter name: " );
fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );
str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Also the function main without parameters according to the C Standard shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

As for the function that finds the length of a string then it should be declared the following way

```
size_t stringlength( const char s[] );
```

and can be impelmented simpler like

```
size_t stringlength( const char s[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while( *s++ != '\0' ) ++n;

    return n;
}
```

Within main you can write

```
size_t len = stringlength(str);
printf("Name length is %zu\n", len);
                       ^^^
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t stringlength( const char s[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while( *s++ != '\0' ) ++n;

    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    char str[N];

    printf( "Enter name: " );

    fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );
    str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    printf( "Your name is %s\n", str );

    size_t len = stringlength( str );
    printf( "Name length is %zu\n", len );  

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter name: Gokul UK
Your name is Gokul UK
Name length is 8
```

Comment: @Adrian Good morning. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code of finding string length without using built-in function. We can write a function without making it very complicated. As a basic learner I might be make these kind of mistakes. Thank you all for putting time to fix my doubt. Happy learning.

```
      #include <stdio.h>

       void main()
  {
       char string[50];
       int i, length = 0;

      printf("Enter a string \n");
      gets(string);

     for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
          length++;
     }

       printf("The length of %s = %d\n", string, length);
      }
```